# How to set relaxed security for Terminal Services on 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-terminal-services

I installed Remote Desktop Services on Windows 2008 Server R2.  I am trying to set it up with 'Relaxed Security' similar to Windows 2003 would have.  Windows 2003 Server, I would set up:

Permission Compatibility = 'Relaxed Security'

That was done simply in the tscc under server settings.

Any way to do that with 2008?  I've been googling for awhile and must be searching poorly because I cannot find it anywhere!

thx.

Comment: There isn't a comparable RDS setting AFAIK. disabling UAC (not recommended) likely achieves the same effect.

Comment: Can you re-form this question to ask what it is you're trying to do?  Trying to mimic the security model of an OS that is unsupported doesn't sound like the best course of action, IMO.